# Incorrect index usage Postgresql Version 12

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, postgresql-performance

**Query Plan:**

```
db=> explain
db-> SELECT MIN("id"), MAX("id") FROM "public"."tablename" WHERE ( "updated_at" >= '2022-07-24 09:08:05.926533' AND "updated_at" < '2022-07-28 09:16:54.95459' );
                                                                                   QUERY PLAN                                                                                    
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Result  (cost=128.94..128.95 rows=1 width=16)
   InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
     ->  Limit  (cost=0.57..64.47 rows=1 width=8)
           ->  Index Scan using tablename_pkey on tablename  (cost=0.57..416250679.26 rows=6513960 width=8)
                 Index Cond: (id IS NOT NULL)
                 Filter: ((updated_at >= '2022-07-24 09:08:05.926533'::timestamp without time zone) AND (updated_at < '2022-07-28 09:16:54.95459'::timestamp without time zone))
   InitPlan 2 (returns $1)
     ->  Limit  (cost=0.57..64.47 rows=1 width=8)
           ->  Index Scan Backward using tablename_pkey on tablename tablename_1  (cost=0.57..416250679.26 rows=6513960 width=8)
                 Index Cond: (id IS NOT NULL)
                 Filter: ((updated_at >= '2022-07-24 09:08:05.926533'::timestamp without time zone) AND (updated_at < '2022-07-28 09:16:54.95459'::timestamp without time zone))
(11 rows)

Indexes:
    "tablename_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "tablename_updated_at_incl_id_partial_idx" btree (updated_at) INCLUDE (id) WHERE updated_at >= '2022-07-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone
```

Idea is when there is already a filtered index which only has small subset of records, why is query doing index scan on primary key, instead of tablename_updated_at_incl_id_partial_idx. Also this is a heap table not clustered table.

Comment: @Laurenz Albe:  Would you please assist here.

Comment: What percentage of the rows is the predicate `"updated_at" >= '2022-07-24 09:08:05.926533' AND "updated_at" < '2022-07-28 09:16:54.95459'` selecting (average)?

Comment: It is not doing what you think it should, but that doesn't necessarily mean it is wrong.  Include the timing data `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`, so we can see the effects of this 'wrongness' in action.

Comment: 'a filtered index which only has small subset of records'  PostgreSQL thinks the subset is 6513960, which doesn't seem all that small.  Is it small in your context?  Is the estimate way off?  Maybe you should ANALYZE the table to make sure the stats are current.

Comment: @jjanes: Yes estimates are correct. I can't show output of EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) because it ran for more than 30 minutes and then I cancelled it since it was consuming all the disk IOPS. Resultset is not small. What I meant by small is: The partial index is small 400MB only while the primary key index is more than 3 GB. So I couldn't understand why partial index is not used instead of primary key.

Comment: @jjanes: Also I can't try dropping index and then calculate planner estimates for both indexes in terms of plans. Is there any better way to do it? I haven't checked pg_statistics but it is evident that primary key index is scanning whole index and is larger while partial index would have to be scanned less.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using MIN and MAX, try redefining your second index so `id` is part of the BTREE index, not just INCLUDEd in it.  That may make searching for the MIN and MAX items faster.

Comment: While it is a good idea to put it in the body of the index rather than an INCUDE, it won't make a difference here, as the first column is being used in a range not an equality.

Comment: @O.Jones:  Why do you think making id part of index will make it better?

Comment: @jjanes: you think it will be better to have id in index column rather than include because if it is in index column list then it is already sorted and hence finding Min and Max is just limit 1, But if id is part of include then after index scan, query executor needs to actually perform sort operation for Min and Max? Any other benefit you see?

Comment: Will the query planner handle the IN-lists as a range or as a sequence of equalities? You won't know until you try it.

Comment: @O.Jones  But there is no in-list, just a BETWEEN.  I don't think the planner will convert a BETWEEN to an in-list, even if the BETWEEN is on a discrete type with a small range. (Maybe it should, but it doesn't.).  I did try it :)

Comment: @MonikaYadav correct, not sort needed if id is in the body of the index rather than the include, but that would only apply if the first column were tested for equality rather than with BETWEEN.  So it won't help you in this case, but still putting it in the INCLUDE when there is no reason to is just betting against yourself.  Doing that can't win, and in some cases you haven't looked at yet it might lose.

Answer (score 0):

Since a small fraction of your table really is over 6e6 rows, then your data must be huge.  And I am guessing that id and updated_at are nearly perfectly correlated with each other, so selecting specifically for recent updated_at means you are also selecting for higher id.  But the planner doesn't now about that.  It thinks that by walking up the id index it can stop after walking about 1/6513960 of it, once it finds the first row qualifying on the time column.  But instead it has to walk most of the index before finding that row.

The simplest solution probably to introduce some dummy arithmetic into the aggregates: `SELECT MIN("id"+0), MAX("id"+0) ...`  This will force it not to use the index on id.  This will probably be the most robust and simplest solution as long as you have the flexibility to change the query text in your app.  But even if you can't change the app, this should at least allow you to verify my assumptions and capture an EXPLAIN (ANALYZE) of it while it is not using the pk index.

None of PostgreSQL's advanced statistics will (as of yet) fix this problem.  so you are stuck with fixing it by changing the query or the indexes.  Changing the query in the silly way I described is the best currently available solution, but if you need to do just with indexes there are some other less-good options but which will likely still be better than what you currently have.

One is to make the horrible index scan at least into a horrible index-only scan. You could replace your existing primary key index with one like `create unique index on tablename (id) include (updated_at)`.  Here the INCLUDE is necessary because otherwise the UNIQUE would not do what you want.  It will still have to walk a large part of the index, but at least it won't need to keep jumping between index and table to fetch the time column. (Make sure the table is well-vacuumed)

Or, you could provide a partial index that the planner would find attractive, by switching the order of the columns in it: `create index on tablename (id, updated_at) WHERE updated_at >= '2022-07-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone`  The only thing that makes this better than your existing partial index is that this one would actually get used.